# How to connect to database in C# using SqlConnection object?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

How can I connect to a remote or local database using simple `SqlConnection` object? I learned to do it this way, but my connection is failing. I read about creation of connection string from this page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

My code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SyncApp_BuiltInProviders
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void btnSynchronize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection source_conn = new SqlConnection();
            source_conn.ConnectionString ="Server=localhost;Database = ptls; UID = root;Password = ODYSSEY99GRANITE;";
            source_conn.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "my connection is failing" - without any more information about *how* it's failing, we're not going to be able to help... (I hope you haven't included your *actual* root password...)

Comment: That _"UID=root"_ let me think about.... What kind of database have you  installed?

Answer (score 3):

As from your comment in another answer it is clear that you are using the wrong classes. The **SqlConnection** is a class specialized in connecting to Sql Server/Sql Server Express/LocalDb. It cannot work against a MySql

If you use MySql then you need to download and install the MySql Connector for NET from [here](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).

After that, you need to reference the *MySql.Data.dll* and add a

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

to all the source files that interact with the database.

Finally, all the classes used to work with the database, should be the ones provided by the MySql NET Connector.

They are prefixed with MySql..... (**MySqlConnection**, **MySqlCommand**, **MySqlDataReader** etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are used SQL Database, it seems to me that, you have not set username and password. If you have not set username and password then try this.

```
private void btnSynchronize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            SqlConnection db_connect= new SqlConnection();

            db_connect.ConnectionString ="Server=[your local pc connection name, it is not local host.];Database=[database_name];Trusted_Connection=true";

            db_connect.Open();
        }
```

Comment: No I am using MySql database

Comment: @M.Dagiya - If you're using MySql, then you _cannot_ use `SqlConnection` or `System.Data.SqlClient` as that is specific for Sql Server.  You should be using `MySqlConnection` I believe

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySql then

```
private void btnSynchronize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

//Create a MySQL connection string.
string connectionString="Server=localhost;Database[database_name];Uid=root;Password =your password; ";

MySqlConnection db_connect= new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

db_connect.Open();
        }
```

Finally use following name space

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```